# When would you use inputAccessoryViewController instead of inputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have used `inputAccessoryView`in the past to add `UIToolbar` on top of the keyboard but I don't see where and why you would use `inputAccessoryViewController`.

What would be an example where `inputAccessoryViewController` has a better fit than `inputAccessoryView`?

Thanks

Comment: When you want to show complicated views/layouts with custom behaviour. One example comes to mind - Facebook Messanger app, when you tap on [GIF] icon - It shows a custom search bar with images above it. While this could be done as a view, it's better to have it as a VC with separated logic IMHO.

Comment: Ah I see, make sense. Thanks a lot. Write this as an answer so I can mark it as answered.

Comment: you can write your own answer since @Losiowaty did not